# IE: center and overlay a div on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

The following code works so so in Firefox, but NOT in IE.

**I need to properly center the div on the screen**
 -Right now the div is leaning too much to the bottom

I also need to make this div (id="loading") to **cover the whole window** -And take all the clicks to prevent clicks somewhere else.

**It needs to be compatible with IE.**

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Overlay</title>
    <link href="loading.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loading.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
This paragraph is for testing
<br/>
Hello world!
<br/>
How are you?
<br/>
Be happy!
<br/>
<input id="cmd" type="button" value="Test" />
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#loading {
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#loading_box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: -15.5px
}

#loading_img {
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
}

#loading_txt {
    color: #49a0dc;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
```

Sample file
http://punkbunny.com/tmp/overlay/overlay.html

Comment: This isn't the _greatest_ question, but why the downvotes?  C'mon, people!  Voice your opinions so he can fix whatever you aren't liking.

Comment: Sorry, this is too localized. You cannot just dump your whole code here and expect us to debug it for you. As an aside, did you try searching the web for a dialog/modal/overlay jQuery plugin instead of rolling your own from scratch?

Comment: @frederic-hamidi I'd say: Why I can't use my own code?!!! This place is to help programmers, expert or not. Not a site that tires to change the way one do things... I am an American and LOVE the 5th amendment that provides us freedom of expression, not repression!!!!

Comment: @xyan-ewing thanks for the vote of "confidence"

Comment: @frederic-hamidi It would have been better to say something like: why don't you try dialog.UI? Instead of a down vote AND telling me how to do things

Comment: Can you guys please help me find what am I doing wrong? I am NOT an expert programmer

Comment: @Omar, you can use your own code if you want, nobody's stopping you from doing so, but you cannot expect us to debug it for you. I was only trying to suggest alternatives, not to *tell* you what to do.

Comment: @frederic-hamidi It's clearly a CSS problem. I threw the whole thing to be specific! I guess you where too busy to notice

Comment: Almost **MOST IMPORTANT** thing in html code is the `DOCTYPE` declaration, which defines the way elements are treated/shown. Yours is not properly closed!! Because of this, all your efforts fall on stony ground, as browsers enter on [Quirks Mode](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Replace it with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: just to help... http://jsfiddle.net/Xwyeb/8/ there is your solution working even on IE6+. Find yourself the way background alpha filter to be displayed on IE. hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#loading_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

instead of your `position: relative;` and `margin`s on the `#loading_box` element. Using those will be a lot harder to get the effect that you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

Your doctype is incorrect and puts IE into quirks mode. Use this one instead and see where we stand: `<!DOCTYPE html>`